# Gmail doesn't load the image sent in html by nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

Generally, I want to know if my clients opened the mail that I have sent earlier by this there are a sequence of tasks that should be done

my mail code is

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
   service: "gmail",
   auth: {
   user: "example@gmail.com",
   pass: "password",
  },
 });
const adress = "http://localhost:3000/example/image/Anveshweb%20development.png";

var mailOptions = {
   from: "from@gmail.com",
   to: "to@gmail.com",
   subject: "Sending Email using Node.js",
   text: "That was easy!",
   html: `<h1>Welcome</h1><p>That was easy!</p><img src=${adress} alt='hello' />`,
 };

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
  }
});
```

at my server I am serving a transparent pixel in response to the request

```
  var buf = new Buffer([
    0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x39, 0x61, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
    0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2c,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
    0x02, 0x44, 0x01, 0x00, 0x3b]);
```

gmail gives out

```
GET https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/LKrNqBK4M96BJZwT3Kj_-glJlHpSg1I33wKM5dqygwg7Emy7kijJWgGPs_uIVfnPUN8Fa7ERW9m1DvX4h6qP792V8XVJ9hHis8Qdbdc=s0-d-e1-ft 404
```

please let me know if there is a solution for it... Thank you

Comment: why your address refers to your local address?

Comment: thanks for the comment babak...! presently the module is in development stage so I use my local machine

Comment: your local machine IP is not valid on the internet

Comment: Thank u babak, I get it now but I got a work around for development purpose by executing the below js code in gmail console                                                                                    `var images = document.querySelectorAll("img"); for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {console.log(images[i].src); images[i].src = images[i].src.replace( /^https:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9.\/\-=_]+#/, ""); }`